# Как прикрепить и открепить машину к водителю на mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Тут сделал приложение, 60% работы уже сделано. Сделал ее на mean.io с базой mongodb. Теперь вот сижу и думаю как бы реализовать связи между документами.

Люди говорят что монго это полная лажа, что нужно использовать SQL. А вот ради одной функции не хочется все переделывать.

Подскажите плз как можно решить следующую задачу с помощью монгодб ?

Для приложения такси, необходимо закрепить авто за водителем, историю водителей необходимо сохранить в коллекцию водителей.

Водители
[image: Водители]

Автомобили 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модель`Водителя

```
var DriversSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true,
        dropDups: true
    },
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        dropDups: true
    },
    car: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Car'
    }
});
```

Модель авто

```
var CarsSchema = new Schema({
    number: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        dropDups: true,
        required: true
    },
    model: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mileage: Number,
    color: String,
    isBusy: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    drivers: [{
        date: Date,
        driver: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Driver',
            required: true
        }
    }]
});
```

Нахожу водителя и сохраняю копию авто

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
      Drivers.get({
        driverId: $stateParams.driverId
      }, function(driver) {
        console.log('driver ', driver);
        $scope.driver = driver;
        $scope.oldCar = driver.car;
        $scope.cars.unshift(driver.car);
      });
    };
```

Обновляю документ

```
$scope.update = function(isValid) {
  if (isValid) {
    var driver = $scope.driver;
    if (!driver.updated) {
      driver.updated = [];
    }
    driver.updated.push(new Date().getTime());
    driver.user = MeanUser.user;
    driver.acl = MeanUser.acl;
    console.log('update driver ', driver);
    if(driver.car){
      driver.car.isBusy = true;
    }
    driver.$update(function() {
      if($scope.oldCar){
        updateCar($scope.oldCar);
      }

      $location.path('drivers/' + driver._id);
    });
  }
  else {
    $scope.submitted = true;
  }
};

function updateCar(oldCar) {
  Cars.get({carId: oldCar._id}, function (car) {
    car.isBusy = false;
    car.$update(function (response) {
      console.log('OldCar updated ', response);
    })
  });
}
```

Как сделать смену авто, сохранять водителей которые ранее ездили на ней ?

Comment: Если хранить историю водителей не обязательно в документе водителей, то можно вынести её в отдельную коллекцию. Где каждый документ будет точкой в истории - показывать водителя, машину и дату смены.

Comment: Ну и в целом правильно вам про монгу сказали. Вы ещё не рассматривали свой код с точки зрения транзакций. И когда, например, между обновлением документов водителя и машины сервер упадет (или вторая операция не выполнится в монге), то получите неконсистентное состояние. Используйте монгу для хранения отзывов пассажиров о водителях, а для важной инфы - посгресс. Иначе будет много лишней работы, чтобы построить надежную систему.

Answer (score 0):

Для таких вещей вы можете хранить в истории водителя только уникальный идентификатор тачки и необходимые данный, а не реальный объект авто:

```
"driver" : {
       "_id": {
          "$oid": "58eb8bb010d68b0ffc070063"
       },
       name: "Иванов Иван Иванович",
       car: "54b8bb610d68b345c070078",
       history: [
          {
              "timeStamp": {
                "$date": "2017-04-18T08:55:08.560Z"
               },
              "carId": "54b8bb610d68b345c070078",
              "id": 1
          }
       ]
    }
```

Уникальный идентификатор и будет служить ссылкой на бэкэнде (связью). Аналогично можно сделать и историю автомобиля, а в каком-нибудь поле "currentDriver" хранить id актуального водителя.